# Not able to get proper for loop and if

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, algpseudocode

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Brute-Force algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\For {$s'$ \in ${\mathbb{F}^n_2}$}{
    \If {$wt(As'+b)$ \leq $t$}{
        return $s'$}
    }
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}

\end{onehalfspacing}
```

Just want to remove this extra part that is marked with red pen
[image: Just want to remove this extra part that is marked with red pen]

Comment: Your code doesn't compile like that. Even adding the required `document` environment and giving it a `documentclass` does not result in that output (but rather a series of errors. Are you sure, these are all the packages you are using?

Comment: yes, I used all the required packages

Comment: Can you maybe provide a combilable minimal working example of you code, which procudes this behaviour? Otherwise, it will be hard to tell what is going wrong here.

Comment: ok I made a change in my doubt

Comment: Hi. Just a hint (in addition to Markus): Please run the code that you provide here on your system before you post it: **Open an empty LaTeX document and paste the code and run/compile it.** Then you can see if the code actually produces the problem. Otherwise, the people here cannot help you efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If the following is the output you were looking for, then you forgot to close the `If` and `For` blocks. Also, there are some issues, with using `\leftarrow` instead of the packages `\gets` and some other minor issues with your way of using math mode:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{Brute-Force algorithm}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \State \textbf{Input:} dimension $d \in \mathbf{N}$, error rate $\tau \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$
                \State \textbf{Output:} secret $\mathbf{s}$
                \State $n$ = $4d $(\( \frac{1}{2} \) - \(\tau\))$^{-2}$ ,
                \State $ (A,b) \gets Orc^n_{d,\tau} $
                \For {$s' \in \mathbf{F}^n_2$}
                    \If{$wt(As'+b) \leq t$}
                        return s'
                    \EndIf
                \EndFor
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If this is what you are looking for and it answers your question, feel free to "accept" the answer by clicking the check-mark. This will also let others know that your question has been answered. If, however, there is still something that is not like you expect it to be, do let me know in a comment and I will try to adapt my answer or someone else may give it a go.